# Chrome/Windows10 Right Click/Context Menu Option Underline on Key missing

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, contextmenu

Hi Everyone i hope you all are safe and healthy.

I have this concern, this years i noticed the underline on letters are gone, they are very helpful since it indicates what keyboard key to press to quickly select an option.

I guess its also helpful for everyone not just me.

**I wonder how well we get that feature again on Chrome and Windows 10**.

---

**BEFORE**

Options have underline on their shortcut char/key

[image][image]

---

**NOW**

Options DONT have underline but still working if you press their shortcut key.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Windows 10, there is an existing settings for that.**

**Step 1: Go to Ease of Access**
To start, hit Windows+I to open up the Settings app. On the main page, click the “Ease of Access” category.

**Step 2: Go to Keyboard**
On the Ease of Access page, choose the “Keyboard” tab on the left. On the right, scroll down a bit and turn on the “Underline Access Keys When Available” toggle under the “Change How Keyboard Shortcuts Work” section.

**Step 3: Test it out**
Once enabled, you’ll start seeing underlined letters in various menus, dialog boxes, and windows. Pressing that letter activates that menu or command.

Here’s how that looks on a context menu you might see when right-clicking a file (it’s enabled on the left and disabled on the right).

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGdby.png)

Or you can follow this instructions: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/make-windows-10-highlight-underline-menu-shortcut-keys/

For Chrome, it doesn't work. I don't have something for it

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Setting explained in the accepted answer has no effect on the menu display in Chrome.

For Chrome you can display the underlines using the trick explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1140859/how-to-change-the-names-of-local-folders-synced-from-sharepoint-with-onedrive-fo/1517119#1517119v):
Press Alt+Shift before Right-Click